# In Excel is there a formula to find a matching cell in another table and grab relevant data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 tables:

1. BigTable
2. SmTable (**a subset of BigTable**)

I want to produce a result that matches info from both tables and produces a result.

Here's a simplified example:
[image: Excel spreadsheet with 2 tables and a result]

I want the Result to show the Body Length for just the items in SmTable (the Terrier and the Pitbull).

Is there a formula I can plug in at the "??" cells?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? There is a wonderful tool in the Data tab [**Power Query**](https://youtu.be/M_jIsnksv7I) (this is not available in older versions) that allows you to solve this problem in a dozen mouse clicks without formulas. Otherwise, you will have to use a formula like `=INDEX(BigTable[Nose to Tail];MATCH(SmTable[@Breed];BigTable[Breed];0))-SmTable[@Tail]`

Comment: Office 365. I watched the YouTube vid you linked. I'll give it a go tomorrow. It looks like it might be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at xlookup

Comment: Do the result have the reference Breed column??

Comment: @Lee No. But the Big and Small tables that I'm actually using have 5 or 6 columns that match (like Breed) and about 100 that don't match. So It would actually be great if I could combine the big and small tables (maybe as described in JohnSUN's shared video?). Then I could just create various result columns normally (=H1-Y1 or whatever)... And I actually have about 6 tables to combine that are all different subsets of the big one. I'll see what works and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Going old school VLOOKUP on this one:

```
=VLOOKUP(E5, B5:C9, 2, FALSE) - F5
```

Where E5 is the first cell e.g. "terrier" in the small table, B5:C9 is the big table, the 2 indicates to return the matching value in the second column of B5:C9 (i.e. nose to tail), the FALSE indicates to search for an exact match and F5 is the tail length for breed in E5.